# Subsonic music server won't autostart. Only launches manually via the terminal

Tags: linux, java

I have this on a headless box with no terminal access.

This is a Java program.

I have tried the following already;

Put the following in `rc.local`:

```
/shared/subsonic/subsonic.sh
```

According to the logs it starts but then is not running. It doesn't show up with `ps aux` so it seems as soon as it starts it dies.

I have also tried:

```
nohup /shared/subsonic/subsonic.sh
```

According to the `nohup.out` file it started, there is no other info.

I have tried putting it in crontab with the following command:

```
@reboot /shared/subsonic/subsonic.sh
```

`crontab` sends me an email saying it is started and gives the process number but it is not there when I log in via ssh.

If I log in via ssh and start it, it runs fine, works like a charm.

So there is something about the output of subsonic needing to be fed to a terminal on startup or it dies.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what version of Linux you are on, but assuming you are using Ubuntu—or a version of Linux with a similar directory layout—this should work too create a true system star up script for Subsonic.

First go into the `init.d` directory on your Linux system like this:

```
cd /etc/init.d
```

Now setup symbolic link from the `subsonic.sh` to `subsonic` in the `/etc/init.d` directory like this:

```
sudo ln -s /shared/subsonic/subsonic.sh subsonic
```

With that done, finally set the system init scripts by using `update-rc.d` like this:

```
sudo update-rc.d subsonic defaults
```

Now this all assumes that `subsonic.sh` can actually be used this way. Assuming the positive, let’s say it works. You should then at least be able to run the following command to start the service:

```
sudo service subsonic start
```

This to stop it:

```
sudo service subsonic stop
```

And assuming it is a proper—and well thought out—startup script you can then run this without a directive:

```
sudo service subsonic
```

And the command line should show you all of the different service options that are connected to Subsonic. Some common ones are `restart` too restart the service as well as `status` to check the service status. Or you could even look inside the `subsonic.sh` script to see what options exist.